# mongoDB PHP query where is NOT

Tags: mongodb, find

ok I need a quick way to do the following with mongoDB

I was looking to do a query that would search for anything that did NOT have the word Apple in the fruit or veg column in the collection

here etc

```
{
 "fruit":"apple"
},{
 "fruit":"orange"
},{
 "fruit":"banana"
}
```

Comment: Apart from that: the data presented is neither a valid BSON document nor data stored that way in a collection...must we guess?

Comment: @Maulwurfn its not BSON but it is JSON which MongoDB uses

Comment: @RussellHarrower I think your confused, the MongoDB console uses JSON, MongoDB is BSON and only BSON. Queries are inputted to the Mongo Server as BSON Documents and Documents are stored and retrieved as BSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator you probably want to use is [$nin](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24nin) ("not in"):

```
db.market.find({
    'fruit': {$nin:['apple']},
    'veg':   {$nin:['apple']}
})
```

You could also use [$not](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-Metaoperator%3A%7B%7B%24not%7D%7D) to negate a standard where condition.

Comment: THANK YOU! that should work, just was not 100% sure if that would work, as I needed to do $NOT and also find other stuff